# How we make Java Code to jump to finally

Tags: java, exception, try-catch-finally

Here's the piece of code I am seeing

```
 1 session s=null; 
 2 try{
 3    s= SessionCreator.createSession();
 4    System.out.println("Session Created");
 5    s.validate(); 
 6 }catch (Exception e){
 7    e.printStackTrace(); 
 8 }finally{
 9    s.close();
10 }
```

Debugger jumps from line 3 to line 9, How is this possible ? Neither 4,5 nor 7 was executed. This puzzles me. line 3 is a vendor code, So I don't know what is happening. Any clues ?

Comment: Are you sure line 4 wasn't executed?

Comment: Are you sure that the class file is **really** synchronized with this source?

Comment: If line 3 throws an exception, execution follows with the `finally` block. If that throws an exception as well (and it will, because `s` has a `null` value at this point, so an NPE is inevitable), that exception will "mask" the original exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If neither line 4 nor line 7 get executed, **maybe** (and I stress the "maybe" because I don't know the Java exception mechanism very in-depth) line 3 is not throwing an `Exception` object, but an `Error` or a `Throwable`.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `catch (Throwable e)` instead of `Exception`. An [Error](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) might be thrown and an error is not subclass of "Exception" but extends "Throwable".

Here is an example: http://ideone.com/Zs7HGw

Answer (score 0):

Read up here.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html

Any code put in the `try` block has the potential to fail.  If it does fail (probably on line 2 or 4), it should break out of the `try` block and into the `catch` block.  The `finally` block will be executed either way.

Your description sounds correct if line 2 is failing, except that line 6 **should** be getting executed.  If line 6 is not getting executed, then your entire `try` block is succeeding.  What is the exact output?

Answer (score 0):

I know this problem only from remote debugging sessions where the underlying code server side does not correspond with the code we see locally. As the debugger only communicates the lines and not the code itself, it can lead to impossible jumps.

Do you debug remotely? Even if not, can you build the whole project again?